# Filas con más coincidencias entre dos dataframes (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, dataframe, comparaciones

Quiero comparar dos DataFrames con el mismo número de columnas pero distinto número de filas y con datos no estandarizados. Quiero obtener la fila de DF2, con más coincidencias con DF1 y mostrar ambas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ejemplo = { "variable1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
            "variable2": ["si", 60, 300, 400, "no", 500],
            "variable3": ["2a", "2b", "2c", "2d","NA", "NA"]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(ejemplo)

ejemplo2 = { "variable1": [1, 2, 2, 1],
            "variable2": [3, "NA", "NA", "si"],
            "variable3": ["j", "b", "e", "a"]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(ejemplo2)
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

El resultado que quiero obtener es un dataframe o una lista con la fila con más coincidencias al comparar todas las filas del DF2 frente a DF1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacerlo con merge, con un count para las coincidencias pero no consigo hacer una comparación para ambos conjuntos completa. No sé por donde avanzar.

Comment: ¿Deseas comparar caracter con caracter o valor con valor? En tu ejemplo del resultado deseado las filas que muestras coinciden en `variable1` y `variable2`, en este caso (Tal vez por casualidad) `variable3` contiene `2a` y `a`, ¿También se debe comparar cada caracter de cada columna para saber si coinciden?, en la columna `variable3` coincidiría la `a` también

Comment: @HeytalePazguato valor con valor. He puesto el ejemplo para reflejar la diferencia, perdón si no ha quedado claro. En resumen, es encontrar la fila del segundo df que mejor se adapta a alguna fila del df1. Sé que no es lo más óptimo, pero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el método `isin()` [(documentación)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) para buscar qué elementos de `df1` están en `df2` y viceversa; luego contar el número de coincidencias en una columna adicional y obtener las filas de cada `dataframe` con mayor valor en la columna adicional

Ejemplo funcional:

```
#Esto es el código de tu pregunta para generar los dataframes
ejemplo = { "variable1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
            "variable2": ["si", 60, 300, 400, "no", 500],
            "variable3": ["2a", "2b", "2c", "2d","NA", "NA"]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(ejemplo)

ejemplo2 = { "variable1": [1, 2, 2, 1],
            "variable2": [3, "NA", "NA", "si"],
            "variable3": ["j", "b", "e", "a"]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(ejemplo2)

#Obtenemos todas las columnas de cualquiera de los dataframe (Ya que son iguales)
cols = list(df1.columns)

#Creamos una nueva columna para contar coincidencias
df1['count'] = 0
df2['count'] = 0

#Iteramos a través de todas las columnas buscando los valores que coincidan
for col in cols:
    df1['count'] += df1[col].isin(df2[col])
    df2['count'] += df2[col].isin(df1[col])

#Concatenamos las filas que tengan el valor máximo en "count" de cada dataframe en un dataframe nuevo
#reset_index(drop=True) sirve para reiniciar los índices en el nuevo dataframe, podrías quitar "drop=True" si deseas saber el índice original de df1 y df2
df3 = pd.concat([df1[df1['count'] == df1['count'].max()], df2[df2['count'] == df2['count'].max()]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    variable1   variable2   variable3   count
0   1           si          2a          2
1   1           si          a           2
```

Si deseas eliminar la columna "count" puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
df3 = df3.drop(columns='count')
```

Comment: Perfectamente funcional. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @uland,  si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.